# eclipse is not starting after hibernate plugin installation

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I installed the hibernate plugin from eclipse market place and after that I restarted eclipse but its not opening now,it simply displays a blank popup after selecting the workspace.

I tried to open in a new workspace too but the result is same.
Also tried the solutions like deleting .metadata etc but no effect.
I'm using eclipse juno and ubuntu 12.04 LTS

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to duplicate entry for org.eclipse.core.commands in bundle.info

File location - eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\ then open bundle.info

searched for org.eclipse.core.commands it had two entries,deleted the lower version.

restarted eclipse -clean option

whenever you find this type of issue after installing new plugin, just check log file try to find out which plugin is causing the problem, then search that in bundle.info.